# Qt - QPushButton shortcut not trigering

Tags: c++, qt

I am having trouble with binding a shortcut to a `QPushButton` through QtCreator.

What I did is to place a button in a `QDialog` and to use auto-connect to connect the `clicked()` signal to a slot. I then set up the property `QAbstractButton::shortcut` to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in the form editor.

When I click the button, the slot gets triggered, but when I press the shortcut, nothing happens.

Here is the code for the ui file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
   <property name="text">
    <string>PushButton</string>
   </property>
   <property name="shortcut">
    <string>Ctrl+N</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

And here is the code for my Dialog class (header and source have been merged):

```
namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0) :
        QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::Dialog)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
    }

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked()
    {
        qDebug() << "click!";
    }

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Dialog dialog;
    dialog.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I managed to make it work with an action in the menubar, I don't understand why it does not seem to work the same.

I am using Qt 5.8.0.

Comment: I find it strange, I tried your code by pressing "Ctrl + N", you could run `Build-> Clean all` and then `Build-> Run qmake`

Comment: I am still having the same issue after following these steps

Comment: You could share your code through github, drive, dropbox or similar.

Comment: Here is a link to the repository: https://github.com/MaxV37/qtbuttonshortcut

Comment: It works for me, what is your OS?

Comment: I am running Manjaro Linux 17.0.1 with KDE Plasma Version 5.9.5 ; Qt 5.8.0 ; kernel 4.9.28-1-MANJARO

Comment: Have you tried if in another Qt application (like QtCreator) shortcuts work as expected? e.g. `Ctrl+N` to create a new file or `Ctrl+O` to open a file?

Comment: These shortcuts do work, even in my own application, as long as the shortcut is assigned to an action in the menubar. I am having this problem with QPushButton. I do not have in mind any application which uses such shortcuts.

Comment: Just use a "&" in the Button text to define a standard shortcut instead? For example "Push&Button" for Alt+B?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably working on a macOS, for which the `ControlModifier` corresponds with the `Command keys` and the `MetaModifier` corresponds to the `Control key` as [documented by Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#KeyboardModifier-enum):

> **Note**: On macOS, the ControlModifier value corresponds to the Command
>   keys on the Macintosh keyboard, and the MetaModifier value corresponds
>   to the Control keys.

Also the documentation of [`QKeySequence`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#details) gives relevant information:

> **Note**: On macOS, references to "Ctrl", Qt::CTRL, Qt::Key_Control and
>   Qt::ControlModifier correspond to the Command keys on the Macintosh
>   keyboard, and references to "Meta", Qt::META, Qt::Key_Meta and
>   Qt::MetaModifier correspond to the Control keys.

So, you should press `Command + N` to trigger the shortcut.

Comment: I am not running macOS. My OS is Manjaro Linux 17.0.1 with KDE Plasma Version 5.9.5 ; Qt 5.8.0 ; kernel 4.9.28-1-MANJARO

Comment: In that case, I will keep the answer because it may be useful for others looking for the same problem (but different solution).

Answer (score 0):

I got around the problem by creating a menubar action triggering the same slot as the button.

Since the shortcuts work (in my case) only with menubar actions, I believe this is a good alternative, because the button that I wanted to have a shortcut triggered one of the main slots of my application.

I did the following:

- Replace the button's auto-connected slot with the action's one
- Connect the button's `clicked()` signal to the action's `triggered()` signal
- Set the shortcut to the action